# Change variable in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

A textview writes "You have meditated 0 times today." i've connected it through an IBOutlet.

Is it possible to increment just the "0" after a code has been completed, and update the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a variable to store the number:

```
var timesMeditated = 0 {
    didSet {
        yourTextView.text = "You have meditated \(timesMeditated) times today"
    }
}
```

Note how I wrote the `didSet` property observer. That will be called when the variable is changed, so whenever you do this:

```
timesMeditated += 1
```

Your text view will update as well.

Answer (score 1):

**The best approach**, updating textView in the counter **didSet**:

```
var mediatationOfDay = 0 {
    didSet {
        myTextView.text = "You have meditated \(mediatationOfDay) times today."
    }
}
```

To answer your initial question, it's possible, but I would not recommend it:

```
var mediatationOfDay = 0
var textValue = "You have meditated 0 times today."

private func incrementMedidationOfTheDay() {
    let oldvalue = mediatationOfDay
    mediatationOfDay += 1
    textValue = textValue.replacingOccurrences(of: oldvalue.description, with: mediatationOfDay.description)
}
```

Also possible:

```
private func incrementMedidationOfTheDay() {
    mediatationOfDay += 1
    myTextView.text = "You have meditated \(mediatationOfDay) times today."
}
```

Comment: Interesting, is there an advantage to these different approaches?

Comment: Well, I use the property didSet only when one thing is affected, in this example, it's ok because we only change one label. Otherwise, I tend to use the last example (using a dedicated function), since one change can lead to multiple actions. Basically, I want to keep my properties didSet as clean/short as possible. it's not an official guideline, it's just how I like to work :)

Answer (score 0):

you can just set whole text again with new text

like

```
yourTextView.text =  "You have meditated \(counter) times today."
```

`counter` is your variable which contains count

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.textView.text = "You have meditated \(counter) times today."
```

Answer (score -1):

you can set it programmatically

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourTxtView: UITextView!
yourTxtView.text = "You have meditated \(count) times today."
```